# Show a Google Map of locations stored in MediaWiki

Tags: google-maps, mediawiki

I'm a contributor to a wiki on the MediaWiki platform. We have a large set of articles representing people/businesses. We are looking for a way to add latitude/longitude data to the articles, and then (hosted outside the wiki) have a Google Map embedded in a page showing all the article locations. I can see there is a format for adding the location metadata to articles:

```
{{Coord|44.112|N|87.913|W|display=title}}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this efficiently, or is the only route to write a service to screen-scrape the wiki and use the data by that route? I think MediaWiki has no way to show a map of article locations?

Comment: You need an extension that allows for data input (possibly by marking up the Coord template, or by harvesting geotags) and one that displays a map. Depending on your exact needs the first could e.g. be [GeoData](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData), [SMW](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/) or [Cargo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo); the second could be [Maps](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Maps) or [Kartographer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Kartographer) (probably not so straightforward to integrate with non-Wikimedia wikis).

Comment: You can consider storing location details in a Google Spreadsheet & hooking it directly to a custom Google Map - http://www.webchick.net/node/132